# How to replace spaces with newlines/enter in a text-file?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have simple text file named "example".

Reading with terminal command: `cat example`

Output:

```
abc cdef ghi jk lmnopq rst uv wxyz
```

I want to **convert** (transform) into following form: (expected output from `cat example`)

```
abc
cdef
ghi
jk
lmnopq
rst
uv
wxyz
```

How can I do this via the command-line?

(This is only an example file, I want to **convert** word's position in vertical-column)

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169995/85039

Answer (score 73, accepted):

A few choices:

1. The classic, use `tr`:

   ```
   tr ' ' '\n' < example
   ```
2. Use `cut`

   ```
   cut -d ' ' --output-delimiter=$'\n' -f 1- example
   ```
3. Use `sed`

   ```
   sed 's/ /\n/g' example
   ```
4. Use `perl`

   ```
   perl -pe 's/ /\n/g' example
   ```
5. Use the shell

   ```
   foo=$(cat example); echo -e "${foo// /\\n}"
   ```

Comment: For the `sed` example I needed to add a `$` to get bash to replace with an actual newline ie: `sed $'s/ /\\\n/g' example`

Comment: Above example for OSX sed, for gnu-sed: `sed $'s/ /\\n/g'`

Comment: @acumartini GNU `sed` (which is the default on Ubuntu, the others aren't relevant on this site) can deal with `\n` without requiring [ANSI-C quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html). So on a GNU system, `sed 's/ /\n/g' example` works fine and there is no need for `sed $'s/ /\\n/g'`.  You needed to add the `$` because macOS uses BSD sed, but that isn't on topic here.

Comment: the lowest denomitator (from sh) is to represent the new line char as `$'\n'` - like in the example for `cut` - applicable to all the rest of the examples as well

Comment: @RadagasttheBrown not sure what you mean. The `$'\n'` syntax is the more limited approach since it is the only one that requires a shell that understands `$'\n'` (for example, `dash` doesn't work well with it). The rest all use robust, portable solutions. So you would never use `$'\n'` in the other commands since that would only make them slightly less universal.

Comment: @terdon - realy?? interestring!!! I write for the bare minimum - plain `sh`, and learnt to use `$'\n'` as the most common denominator. I never thought that `dash` won't understand it... omg. what a gotcha that is for me!!

Comment: @terdon - OMG. I just found I was testing against `busybox` sh, which is more sophisticated than plain POSIX.... <facepalm>...  tsk tsk tsk... thanks for the eye opener.
anyway - according to https://serverfault.com/questions/241959/whats-the-busybox-default-shell - it seems to be ash / older dash - so `$'\n'` works in dash...

Answer (score 17):

Try the below command:

```
awk -v RS=" " '{print}' file
```

Or:

```
awk -v RS='[\n ]' '{print}' file
```

Example:

```
$ awk -v RS=" " '{print}' example
abc
cdef
ghi
jk
lmnopq
rst
uv
wxyz
```

**Explanation:**

`RS` (Record Separator) is a built-in `awk` variable. In the first command, the value given to the `RS` variable is space (`" "`). `awk` breaks the line from printing whenever it finds a space.

In the second command, the value given to the `RS` variable is a new line character or space (`'[\n ]'`). This command eliminates the extra blank line that appears when running the first command.

Answer (score 11):

You can use `xargs`,

```
cat example | xargs -n 1
```

or, better

```
xargs -n 1 < example
```

Answer (score 3):

Using a `perl` oneliner:

```
perl -p -i -e 's/\s/\n/g' example
```

It will replace spaces and tabs with "ENTER" (aka `\n`)

Answer (score 3):

No one posted python, so here's that:

```
python -c "import sys;lines=['\n'.join(l.strip().split()) for l in sys.stdin.readlines()];print('\n'.join(lines))" < input.txt
```

We redirect input file into `python`'s stdin stream, and read it line by line. Each line is stripped of its trailing newline, split into words, and then rejoined into one string where each word is separated by newline.This is done to ensure having one word per line and avoid multiple newlines being inserted in case there's multiple spaces next to each other. Eventually we end up with list of strings, which is then again joined into larger string, and printed out to stdout stream. That later can be redirected to another file with `> out.txt`  redirection.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to the `tr` in [@terdon's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/461153/618353), but with the additions:

- Also works for tabs
- Converts multiple spaces or tabs to 1 newline

```
tr -s '[:space:]' '\n' < example
```

Comment: This was the fastest for me, processing millions of lines.